# Apply textblob in for each row of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, textblob

i have a data frame with a col which has text. I want to apply textblob and calculate sentiment value for each row.

```
text                sentiment
```

this is great
great movie 
great story

When i execute the below code:

`df['sentiment'] = list(map(lambda tweet: TextBlob(tweet), df['text']))`

I get the error:

```
TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'float'>
```

How do you apply textBLob to each row of a col in a dataframe to get the sentiment value?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [.apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['sentiment'] = df['text'].apply(lambda tweet: TextBlob(tweet).sentiment)
```

Sentiment returns a namedtuple of the form Sentiment(polarity, subjectivity).

But are you sure each row of `df['text']` is in string format?  If not, you could try below to return `None` if the text cannot be processed by TextBlob:

```
def sentiment_calc(text):
    try:
        return TextBlob(text).sentiment
    except:
        return None

df['sentiment'] = df['text'].apply(sentiment_calc)
```